# Typescript unfold object type

Tags: typescript

```
type A = {
  a: {
    b: string
    c: string
  }
  x: {
    y: number
    z: number
  }
}
```

i want to:

```
type B = {
  b: string
  c: string
  y: number
  z: number
}
```

...
implemented through generic type

```
type B = Unfold<A>
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, we need to get the values of every key of `A` (or any generic `A`-like object):

```
type GetValues<T extends {[key: string]: any}> = T[keyof T];
```

This generic let's us pass in an `A`-like object and produces a [*union*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of all the objects at every key of `A`. For demonstration purposes, let's use it to declare a new type `Foo` based on `A`:

```
type Foo = GetValues<A>;
```

If we hover over `Foo` we'll see the type it represents - as described above, the union of all the objects at each key of `A`.

[image]

This is close, but we don't want a union, we want an [*intersection*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#intersection-types) of all the possible types, per your requirement. Fortunately [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286/4897779) on SO has already solved the issue of converting a union to an intersection.

```
type UnionToIntersection<U> = 
  (U extends any ? (k: U)=>void : never) extends ((k: infer I)=>void) ? I : never;
```

Now we have everything we need, we can construct our final generic `Unfold<T>` which composes those two bits:

```
type Unfold<T extends {[key: string]: any}> = UnionToIntersection<GetValues<T>>;
```

Now we can use `Unfold<T>` to convert any `A`-like type definition to its "unfolded" version:

```
type UnfoldedA = Unfold<A>;

const foobar: UnfoldedA = {b: '', c: '', y: 0, z: 0};
```

[All put together](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeAoKUCGAuZb1QCMcBnYAJwEsA7Acz3QGMTzq70BfPADx1XyhA4qAVwC2BCGXpQAXkLESpHFJxShIUAOIRgANQwAbYRGIAeACpQIXYBCoATYsgDaAawiCopSrQC6ODCoQdgA%20BChzNw8AewAzCN8AbhQ1cGgAMWjo8O09Q2MzGBDk1I0AVSoKaKpzaIBJKlsyYggGYCqqUzKwxDwACjKrGztHTCCoAH4oPtccMoBKeBCAN2iKeyghCGXJeaHbByc%20mZxqWMkoOsWVtfs9qbrNqCptyRL1aArY6IN7C32Rk4kFFPN5WP4xsEelAKh1ag0mi02h1TLl9EYTBYQsUUh8YVRvr8IPY4Igvj8-kUSgxqqQoN9ogQMGQ5gSKcTScgiFAAOQ8gA0UCYvIFAhwAAZBXIoOL2IkgA).

Comment: Unfortunatelly it does not work with one more level of nesting

Comment: @captain-yossarian that was not specified in the original question as a requirement. If it were, this could be modified to recursively "unfold" nested objects using conditional types.

Comment: Sure, no problem. Sometimes this can be an issue. I did not want to say that your solution  is not correct. You have my upvote

Comment: Yes, I don't need nesting. This answer perfectly solves my problem. I stay at `{...} | {...}`, `UnionToIntersection` helps me a lot. Thanks！

Comment: Just as a suggestion. Rewrite `GetValues` using distribution for input types defined as unions: `type GetValues<T> = T extends {[key: string]: any} ? T[keyof T] : never`. It still holds the same behavior for non-union types aswell.

Answer (score 2):

I hope smbd will come up with something more readable ))

```js
type A = {
    a: {
        b: string
        c: string
    }
    x: {
        y: number
        z: number,
        w: {
            u: number
        }
    }
}
type Primitives = string | number | boolean | symbol

/**
 * Get all valid nested pathes of object
 */
type AllProps<Obj, Cache extends Array<Primitives> = []> =
    Obj extends Primitives ? Cache : {
        [Prop in keyof Obj]:
        | [...Cache, Prop] // <------ it should be unionized with recursion call
        | AllProps<Obj[Prop], [...Cache, Prop]>
    }[keyof Obj]

// credits goes to https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286
type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends (
    k: infer I
) => void
    ? I
    : never;

/**
 * Iterate through each array of nested keys
 * and get last Prop/Value
 */
type Util<Obj, Props extends ReadonlyArray<Primitives>> =
    Props extends []
    ? Obj
    : Props extends [infer First]
    ? First extends keyof Obj
    ? Obj[First] extends Primitives ? Record<First, Obj[First]> : {}
    : never
    : Props extends [infer Fst, ...infer Tail]
    ? Fst extends keyof Obj
    ? Tail extends string[]
    ? Util<Obj[Fst], Tail>
    : never
    : never
    : never

type Unfold<T> = UnionToIntersection<Util<A, AllProps<T>>>

type Result = Unfold<A>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeAoK6oEMBcy0YICNcBnYAJwEsA7Ac3wPQGNSKb6CBfBqAD11SMMIXNQCuAW0IRyPAgC9Rk6eQA0cjAHcBGoWKVSZuqNy4puoSFAAKVCZWCUAbhBIIoZKnSgAfKOMNyXyhCAHtQgBsITGpgkhApSJQUAHoAKjS0NKgAcQhgLAiIqCdMCMoAE39XYAgqsExgAAtXKFCAMzbCACsIJmAslJRLaBgi21CwEgAeAHke1SgAYUwmFqgIXlrqCrcYcnJMEGnbSntHFxIAPncAbQBdG-geee6NrYgdt1Pz51aAfmWq3WOiE6FuEzAUBoUAA1hAQB0oK97thjH5bgA6bErNYQRaQ%205QFIpKDTAC0lKp0IKJCaoTEESq0igYmolFC7PkdSgmgcTSg5D6YnIJA5sSYZQi6Ng43Ikxmrwh8rA90WWJxwPxNhVjx4nFu8MRnRRyRJUCYQoqDjctFCrWAoSgTWAwCm2BJZFWsNCLnI7QioU0mKYoQkKUwKQArAAGADMAHYowAmAAcADZhuBoABVdmcgAqoQAktRaqK%20o5OdMc08oAAKHPvba7LDUEBQQH12G4HMASgQNycoUqUFEED9A82Lbc9Z4Peh1HaMigxZQA-gQ5HFR4gLXBHHfoA3GaMllV%20XGtBmvKxLQBdE1lgDkc2p1qDUeUaSOeYlVaPkUARJgZA6pMKQAGplGIECDFmVg5o4ERzAsYFTM2nytgAStEFSchEID7Icxw-A4fzXE8PCQm406YW4Dy7siPQ8Lg1EYV8UC3DQy5BAAYpQorAPcjH8YJ7GtkaSKvIxSqiWQRK0RxpEXACUA4aG5AVNMcnAIsskCfJNwCKYGCHkYB5oTRHwcVxS4rrxZCLNimLcSuBaYJQETCQQgIOQUikSQiUnMT5UDuZ54luJ47AMaFiGeSh3S3H5aphR5ERXCx1R%20llH45RZeVGPBuZLpEWkFnWebikWpbliQlbijWSHTDAixjBE1HTBVVyZcVamuIyBSIHm7RlS1VxAA)

Explanation about `AllProps` and `Util` utils you can find [in my blog](https://catchts.com/deep-pick) and

Comment: Thanks！Great answer, but I will adopt @jered because his answer is easier to understand, and this answer will help people who need nesting

Comment: Sure, no problem!